# CheckboxList MVC EditorFor Template PostBack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I inherited some incomplete code. The developer was using an editorfor template for creating his checkboxlist. The problem is that it does not bind back to the model so that I can get the data back to the server side.
Anyone have an example on how to use an editorfortemplate for a checkboxlist and send data back bound to the model?
Below is the editortemplate content.

**EDITOR TEMPLATE** called ServiceTypeViewModel.cshtml

```
     @model List<ViewModels.ServiceTypeViewModel>
<table>

@{int k = 0; int columns = 2;}

@for (int i = 0; i < (Model.Count / columns + (Model.Count % columns == 0 ? 0 : 1)); i++)
{
    <tr>
    @for(int j = 0; j<columns; j++){
        <td>
            @if (k<Model.Count) { 
                <input name="ProvidedServices[@(k)].Name" id="ProvidedServices__@(k)__Name" type="hidden" value="@Model[k].Name">       
                <input name="ProvidedServices[@(k)].Selected" class="CB" id="ProvidedServices__@(k)__Selected" type="checkbox" value="true">
                <input name="ProvidedServices[@(k)].Selected" type="hidden" value="false">
                <input name="ProvidedServices[@(k)].ServiceTypeClass" id="ProvidedServices__@(k)__ServiceTypeClass" type="hidden" value="@Model[k].ServiceTypeClass">       
                <input name="ProvidedServices[@(k)].ServiceType" id="ProvidedServices__@(k)__ServiceType" type="hidden" value="@Model[k].ServiceType">       
                @Html.DisplayFor(m=>Model[k].Name)
                k++;
            }
        </td>
    }
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**MODEL BELOW**

```
  public class ServiceTypeViewModel
    {
        public string ServiceTypeClass { get; set; }
        public string ServiceType { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public string Name { get { return ServiceTypeClass + " " + ServiceType; } }
    }
}
```

EditorFor Template Definition in main Model.

```
[UIHint("ServiceTypeViewModel")]
public List<ServiceTypeViewModel> ProvidedServices { get; set; }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProvidedServices)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ProvidedServices)
```

How can I get it to display as a List?

[image]

I got it to render within the template like the picture above but the postback returns providerservices as null. The code below renders the two columns of checkboxes.

```
@model List<ViewModels.ServiceTypeViewModel>
<table>
 @{int k = 0; int columns = 2;}

@for (int i = 0; i < (Model.Count / columns + (Model.Count % columns == 0 ? 0 : 1)); i++)
{
   <tr>
    @for(int j = 0; j<columns; j++){
     <td>
   @if (k<Model.Count) { 
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[k].Name);
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[k].ServiceTypeClass);
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[k].ServiceType);
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[k].Selected);
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[k].Name);
  k++;
      }
        </td>
    }
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ServiceTypeViewModel.cshtml` to

```
@model ViewModels.ServiceTypeViewModel

<tr>
  <td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m > m.ServiceTypeClass)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m > m.ServiceType)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m > m.Selected)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
  </td>
</tr>
```

and ensure its located in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder (or `/Views/yourConrollerName/EditorTemplates` folder)

Side note: Its not clear what you variables `k` and `columns` are supposed to be doing, but this editor template will generate the correct html for each item in your collection

**Edit (based on revised question)**

If you want a 2 column layout, then modify the template to use a `<div>` element and use css to style it

```
@model ViewModels.ServiceTypeViewModel
<div>
  @Html.HiddenFor(m > m.ServiceTypeClass)
  ....
</div>
```

and in the main view

```
<div id="container">
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ProvidedServices) 
</div>
```

and the css

```
#container div {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Which will produce a 2 column as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvmakwmw/1/)

Alternatively if you do want to use a table (its not really appropriate since tables are for tabular data) then you cannot use an `EditorTempate`. Instead you need to use a `for` loop in the main view

```
<table>
  <tr>
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.ProvidedServices.Count; i++)
    {
      <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProvidedServices[i].ServiceTypeClass)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProvidedServices[i].ServiceType)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ProvidedServices[i].Selected)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProvidedServices[i].Selected, Model.ProvidedServices[i].Name)
      </td>
      if((i + 1) % 2 == 0)
      {
        @:</tr><tr>
      }
    }
  </tr>
</table>
```

Side note: Including a hidden input for property `Name` is a bit pointless. Its a readonly property (no setter) so it will not be bound anyway.

Comment: I updated the question. Can you help me get it to render as a list as shown in the picture?

Comment: Sure, but you cannot use an `EditorTemplate` for that. You will need to use a `for` loop in the view so that you can generate 2 columns per row. No time now (its late) but  will update the answer in the morning.

Comment: But to get you started, have a look at [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jXmvLy)

Comment: Actually you could use the `EditorTemplate`, but use a `<div>` element rather than a `<td>`, and style it (e.g. `display:inline-block; float; left; width: 40%;`)

Comment: I got it to render inside an editor template but the LIST for ProvidedServices is null on post back. I will update question

Comment: Thanks. You have skills!